# Should removeFrom* method remove child item from a DB or it should just remove the parent-child relation?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

The question is in the subj.

Currently, the behavior I observe is that when I call `Parent.removeFromChilds(child)`, child is not removed from my DB (i.e. I can find it with `Child.findBy...(args)`).

I'm curious if it's the correct behavior. If yes - what's the best way to remove both relation and child within one transaction?

If no - what may I do wrong?

Comment: I don't find this to be true.  When I do a similar parent.removeFromChildren(child) and then parent.save(flush: true) the child is removed from the collection and deleted from the database (assuming there were no errors).

Comment: @Gregg: I'm doing exactly the same. There're no errors. The only thing I can think of is the way I verify the behavior: it works as described when I unit test the parent (and I've never tested it with a real DB yet).

Answer (score 3):

By default, deletes cascade if you delete the owning side of a one to many.  If you just remove the child, it will not delete.  You can change that by specifying the custom cascading behavior of 'all-delete-orphan' on the owning side of the relationship.  From the Grails doc:

```
class Person {

String firstName

static hasMany = [addresses: Address]

static mapping = { addresses cascade: "all-delete-orphan" } }
```

**Update**

[Part 2 of GORM Gotchas](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/) has a really good breakdown of the not-so-obvious `addTo` and `removeFrom` behavior.  I think it contains the exact information you're looking for.